# Service worker behavior when same app is opened on more than one tab?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Hello every one i have been trying my hands at progressive web apps and have come across a issue i cant seem to fathom. Pardon me if the question seems a bit naive but i am still a newbie in this service worker and fetch, cache api concepts in javascript. The issue is that i have a simple app that registers a service worker which works fine (in offline mode also) but when i open the same app in another tab i observe all the service worker install and activate messages i have logged once again in the console. According to my understanding once a service worker is installed the browser doesn't re-installs it if it hasn't changed so why am i seeing these logs when i open the same pwa in another tab.Note also that i have observed the service worker id/number is always the same in both the instances of pwa opened in the 2 tabs which leads me to believe that the same service worker is registered. the preserve log option is unchecked in dev tools and so is the update on reload option. can some one clarify?

Comment: I believe that you can only have a service worker installed once. When I look here in chrome with multiple tabs open, I only see one - chrome://inspect/#service-workers

Comment: If you are on twitter, that is a good question for Jeff Posnick https://twitter.com/jeffposnick

Answer (score 0):

Never completing the "install" can cause the situation of "multiple service workers".
The Promise provided to `installEvent.waitUntil()` determines the success or failure of the service worker installation.

> The `install` events in service workers use `waitUntil()` to hold the service worker in the `installing` phase until tasks complete. If the promise passed to `waitUntil()` rejects, the install is considered a failure, and the installing service worker is discarded. This is primarily used to ensure that a service worker is not considered installed until all of the core caches it depends on are successfully populated.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ExtendableEvent/waitUntil

In my scenario, I added a listener to the `install` event but never used the event nor provided a resolution to the state of my service worker.
Thus opening a new tab or developer tools, caused it to attempt to install the service worker again and executing all the code over and over.

Furthermore, the `active` event also has a `waitUntil()` that is to be called to provide the state of the service workers activation. This allows loading dependencies prior to `fetch` event handling.