# How to handle service worker message once for multiple tabs?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have an application and I would like prevent message handling from another tab.

```js
//client

var msg_chan = new MessageChannel();
// Handler for recieving message reply from service worker
msg_chan.port1.onmessage = function(event){
  if(event.data.error){
    reject(event.data.error);
  }else{
    resolve(event.data);
  }
};
const id = (new Date().getTime() / 1000).toFixed()
// Send message to service worker along with port for reply
navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage({ message, id }, [msg_chan.port2]);
```

In this way, if multiple tabs are opened service worker handles the message in both tabs.

```js
// service-worker.js
self.addEventListener('message', event => {
  console.log(event.data) // This prints two times if two tabs are open
})
```

Is it possible to handle message for once?

Comment: Ensure you call the appropriate `waitUntil()` methods to keep the service workers state up-to-date. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78150857/3022603)

Comment: It is possible for the logs to appear in multiple developer tools, due to the service worker handling multiple contexts.

Answer (score 1):

You can [assign each tab a clientId](https://www.jameslmilner.com/post/tab-state-service-workers/) and send it on the messages.

Comment: This answer is simply wrong. There's one (1) SW controlling both tabs. Each tab individually send the msg. Thus multiple msgs.