# What happens to a Service Worker when a new tab is opened under the same scope?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker

I am implementing a Service Worker with a React app. I am using the Service Worker to add an Authorization header to every `fetch` request coming from the controlled window (API calls as well as images and other assets). The React app gets a token from an identity provider (Keycloak), and then sends this to the Service Provider. Here is a simplified flow:

1. The React app loads
2. The React app loads the Service Worker using a Javascript file on the same host.
3. The React app registers the Service Worker using

```js
navigator?.serviceWorker?.register('/myServiceWorker.js', { scope: '/' }).then(() => {
 navigator.serviceWorker.controller?.postMessage({
    type: 'MY_TOKEN'
 });
}
```

The interesting thing is that this works fine on first load, but when I open another tab and run the same app, it doesn't work - I can't access the `navigator.serviceWorker.controller` and use the `postMessage` method - because `navigator.serviceWorker.controller` is `undefined`.

I think this is because there is only one copy of the Service Worker, but 2 copies of the React app running. When the second tab opens, the React script runs, loads the Service Worker, but the browser sees that the new tab is within the scope of the Service Worker, so it does not run the initialization of the Service Worker again. However, this seems to avoid having the Service Worker claim the new window or something which prevents the Service Worker from registering the new window with a controller? Or is it just a race condition of some kind?

EDIT: Additionally, and somewhat strangely, if I refresh the 2nd tab, it will work *every other time*. This seems to be reliable.

Comment: I am not sure if this is related, especially when code "sometimes works", but an incorrect service worker state could cause mishaps in the code. [More detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78150857/3022603)